# Dictionary - printing result multiple times?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm coding this program but running it and typing "2" when I type a subject it doesn't print the result once but nine times. Where is the problem? 9 is the number of subjects in the list named `mat` so it's strictly connected. Now to check some files .txt as placeholder but I'd like also using the module `json`.

```
import os

def spat():
    a=len(list(os.listdir('C:/Users/SUINO/Desktop/python/prob/cache/'+y)))
    print(a)
    b=100/(25-a)
    print(b)

mat=["latino","greco","storia","latino","scienze","matematica","grammatica",
     "promessi sposi,","eneide"] #mat means subject

c=input("Do you want to add a placeholder or calculate probabilties? 1|2: ")
if c == "1":
    c=input("Insert a subject: ")
    c=c.lower
    if c in mat:
        name=input("Insert the name of the student: ")
        open('C:/Users/SUINO/Desktop/python/prob/cache/'+c+'/'+name+".txt")
    else:
        print("Materia non esistente!")
if c == "2":
    y=input("Materia: ")
    y=y.lower()
    x={"latino":spat(),"greco":spat(),"eneide":spat(),"promessi sposi":spat(),
       "mate":spat(),"grammatica":spat(),"storia":spat(),"scienze":spat(),
       "inglese":spat(),}
```

The objective of the program is to calculate the probabilities of being interrogated using the files .txt that have as name the name of the student interrogated yet.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Your last line calls `spat()` 9 times, and each time will print two things.

Comment: As an aside, there are several big errors in your code. For example, `c=c.lower` is setting `c` equal to the bound-method `.lower`. It will **never be in `mat`**. You want to actually *call* the method: `c.lower()`. Also, why are you using `open('C:/...')` but never assigning to anything? That is a totally useless line.

Comment: @glibdud yes. And furthermore, `spat` doesn't actually `return` anything, so it will implicitly return `None`, and not the value of the calculation, which is only `print`ed

Comment: `c=c.lower` assigns a bound method to `c`.  To actually invoke the method, you need to use `c=c.lower()`

Comment: If you want to create a dictionary with functions as values, you need to make them references to the function, not actual functions, otherwise it's trying to set the value for each key as the output of the function, rather than each key being a reference to that function.  Also, what purpose does mapping each function do for you if you're not going to pass in any variable to the function?  You're just running the same function for each option, if I'm not mistaken in your dictionary keys being 'options' for the prompt.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @martineau It's: Why does when I run that it prints nine times the result?

Comment: The original runs 9 times because when you declare dictionary `x`, you are assigning the key values (grammatica, latino, greco, storia, etc.) as the output of the function `spat()`.  Calling a function with `()` will run that function and, as a result, your key value is being assigned the value of the return of that function.  So it has to run the function 9 times (for every key value).

Comment: Mader n fader: If that's all. my [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399424/355230) explains the "why" behind it—but apparently you really wanted to know more than that (which is the reason I asked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're basically trying to create a CLI for accessing homework or other school work that students can interact with and access their files.

I just noticed you are also trying to access var `y` within function `spat()`.  You need to pass this value into the function call.  If you want to map each key to the function.

If you want the key to be a reference, you need to structure your dict like this:

```
x = {
    'latino': spat,
    'greco': spat,
    ...
}
```

Then when the user enters in a value, you simply declare a new variable to be the value of the key, which in turn, creates a variable which is a reference to that function.

So if you receive input `y` with

```
y = input("Materia: ")
```

Then you should create a new variable like such

```
func = x[y]
```

This will find the key value entered in from the above input function and assign that reference to the variable `func`.  Essentially, `func` now is equal to the function and you can execute `func` like any other normal function as well as pass in variables.

```
func(y)
```

This will execute the function referenced (spat) and pass in variable y.  You also need to rewrite `spat()` as such:

```
def spat(y):
    a = len(list(os.listdir('C:/Users/SUINO/Desktop/python/prob/cache/'+y)))
    print(a)
    b = 100/(25-a)
    print(b)
```

Essentially the same except you're now passing in `y` from the input below.

You also need to move the declaration of the dictionary to the top so that your reference to this dictionary will be recognized when you declare `func`.

So whole code:

```
import os

def spat(y):
    a = len(list(os.listdir('C:/Users/SUINO/Desktop/python/prob/cache/'+y)))
    print(a)
    b=100/(25-a)
    print(b)
x = {"latino":spat,"greco":spat,"eneide":spat,"promessi sposi":spat,
   "mate":spat,"grammatica":spat,"storia":spat,"scienze":spat,
   "inglese":spat,} # x moved up from bottom
mat = ["latino","greco","storia","latino","scienze","matematica","grammatica",
     "promessi sposi,","eneide"] #mat means subject

c = input("Do you want to add a placeholder or calculate probabilties? 1|2: ")
if c == "1":
    c = input("Insert a subject: ")
    c = c.lower
    if c in mat:
        name = input("Insert the name of the student: ")
        open('C:/Users/SUINO/Desktop/python/prob/cache/'+c+'/'+name+".txt")
    else:
        print("Materia non esistente!")
if c == "2":
    y=input("Materia: ")
    y=y.lower()
    func = x[y] # creates reference to the key which is a ref to a function
    func(y)
```

However, since every key value is executing the same function, you might be better served not writing new dictionary entries for each new key and just simply making a list of recognized subjects that the student may enter:

```
subjects = ['latino', 'greco', 'grammatica', ...]
```

Then you can simply check whether the input exists within this list and, if it does, run `spat()` and pass in `y`.

```
if y in subjects:
    spat(y)
else:
    print("Unrecognized command...")
```

Mapping functions within a dictionary is useful for creating an 'interface' that can route the various inputs to a function that will be executed for that given option.  You can check whether or not their command works by simply checking for their input within a list/dict and if it doesn't exist, then you can skip running the function and output an error message--if the command exists, then you can reference it to a key value (which in turn, references it to the value of that key) and then it will run the proper function.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is it's printing nine times because of all the calls to `spat()` you put in the statement:

```
x={"latino":spat(),"greco":spat(),"eneide":spat(),"promessi sposi":spat(),
   "mate":spat(),"grammatica":spat(),"storia":spat(),"scienze":spat(),
   "inglese":spat(),}
```

There are a number of other issues with your code, but since I don't completely understand everything it's trying to accomplish, I'm not going to attempt to tell you what to do other than not to call it some many times like that.